# How do I pass the resulting docker image from CodeBuild to be referenced in the test section of CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying out Copilot and I've gotten as far as running a couple of services inside an app in a single environment. Currently I'm stuck trying to figure out how to run tests on the the image that was built in the previous CodeBuild step. I see `$image_id` and `$repo` [referenced](https://gist.github.com/jslusher/eab02ebdb0e6eaa80b0bb0ea220a8929#file-buildspec-yml-L101) in my `buildspec.yml`, but I can't find how I might be able to pass that on to use in the `test` section of my `pipeline.yml`. The idea here is that I'm hoping to run tests on that image as the final step before deployment.

```
stages:
    - # The name of the environment to deploy to.
      name: test
      test_commands:
      - docker run --rm REFERENCE_TO_MY_CODEBUILD_CONTAINER pytest
```

Comment: Add it to the artifacts for the codepipeline [docker build -o](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) to pass on or use [ecr](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)

Comment: I am using ECR since this is Copilot. The problem here is that I don't know how to programmatically retrieve $image_id and $repo. I could hardcode $repo once it's set up for me, but $image_id will be different with each build. When you say "add it to the artifacts..." are you saying there's a way to export those variables?